# Expressjs POST error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am new to nodeJS and expressJS, Currently getting the below error from expressJS:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at C:\Users\jitheshlive\IdeaProjects\nodejs-express-start\server.js:37:31
at callbacks (C:\Users\jitheshlive\IdeaProjects\nodejs-express-start\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:161:37)
at param (C:\Users\jitheshlive\IdeaProjects\nodejs-express-start\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
at pass (C:\Users\jitheshlive\IdeaProjects\nodejs-express-start\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:142:5)
at Router._dispatch (C:\Users\jitheshlive\IdeaProjects\nodejs-express-start\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:170:5)
at Object.router (C:\Users\jitheshlive\IdeaProjects\nodejs-express-start\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
at next (C:\Users\jitheshlive\IdeaProjects\nodejs-express-start\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:199:15)
at C:\Users\jitheshlive\IdeaProjects\nodejs-express-start\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:107:5
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\jitheshlive\IdeaProjects\nodejs-express-start\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:136:7)
at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:260:16)
```

My expressJS code is as below:

```
app.configure(function(){

app.use(express.logger());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.engine('html',engines.underscore);
/*
 Set views direcoctory. DO NOT set this with the static directory!. 
*/
app.set('views', __dirname+'/app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.set('PORT',config.server.port);
});

app.get("/", function(req,res){
res.render('index');
});

app.post("/webservice-1.0/rest/student/add/", function(req,res){
    console.log(req.param.student.name);
    console.log(req.param.student.address);
//res.render('index');
});
```

I am using angularJS in the UI to submit the data. My angularJS controller is as below:

```
mainApp.controller("addStudentController", function($scope,$http) {
var resData = {};
$scope.output = "";
var url = "/webservice-1.0/rest/student/add/";
$scope.addStudent = function(){
    $http.post(url, $scope.student)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        resData = angular.fromJson(data);
        $scope.output = "Student entered successfully with unique Id "+resData.id;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        resStatus = status;
        $scope.output = "Something went wrong. Please try again later."
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is no `req.param.student.name`. To see what is coming from the client side to the server side, simply do :

`console.log(req.body)`

You're sending the data with the request body, not params.

Then something like `req.body.data.name` or `req.body.data.student.name` would work.